# Windows Git GUI over ssh?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a test web server with git repository in it. Sometimes my coworkers need to edit the code in there and then commit and push it to production server without me being there.

They can use Notepad++ over (s)ftp to edit the files, but they're not used to console commands.

Is there any git repository managers that can handle ssh?
Or if there any web-based git managers allowing to commit and push i could put on my Ubuntu 14.04 test server?

My last option is to use use .bat files that use ssh client(like putty) to send commit and push commands to the server.

Comment: Have you tried https://windows.github.com/ ?

Comment: This works only with github repos, not my own hosted repos..

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh). Maybe *gitk* suffices?

Comment: My server does not run desktop enviroment, and also remote desktop would be kindof overkill i would belive

Comment: You don't have to run desktop environment on the server to be able to run `gitk` and `git gui` there while rendering their windows locally -- using [VcSrv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) for instance -- tunneling the traffic through SSH. You'll need only a minimal subset of the X and Tk libraries.

Comment: On the other hand, I can't fathom what's wrong with just making  your devs learn some minimal command-line Git. It really is not hard to grok, and if they'll fail at it you don't want them *develop you anything* in the first place.

Comment: Okay, i'll dive into gitk a bit more. And they arent developers, they are just regular office workers(one of the is my boss) who know bit html and css and need to make minor changes over time. And i'd like to make it as hassle-free :)

Comment: @Kristian, when replying to someone's comment, include the `@authorname` in yours, otherwise the author of the comment you're replying to won't get any notification of your answer.  And people do not really poll places where they commented; I found this your comment purely by accident ;-)

Comment: @Kristian any progress in this? I have the exact same scenario here.

Comment: @Vik No, i ended up with different solution. Made a portable pack with Eclipse and Xampp, Eclipse has git capailities, and now my main git is hosted in assembla.com from where i have some buttons to send ssh command to production server for pulling new changes